# Unable to login to Ubuntu in ASUS ROG Zephyrus

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, asus, bootloader, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows in my ASUS Zephyrus ROG. The Grub is not showing up. I tried going to my BIOS and manually selected the Linux to boot up. It's still not working.

I have attached my Bootloader repair results.

```
boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20210311_1041]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================


md/imsm0: ______________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

md/imsm1: ______________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on nvme0n1p8

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, bionic, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0005,0006,0007
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,ccf28906-447b-4ad4-ad94-d535fc48b4ce,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,ccf28906-447b-4ad4-ad94-d535fc48b4ce,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO
Boot0005* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,ccf28906-447b-4ad4-ad94-d535fc48b4ce,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO
Boot0006* UEFI:  USB    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(18,0)/CDROM(1,0x35d8,0x4d00)..BO
Boot0007* UEFI:  USB, Partition 2   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(18,0)/HD(2,MBR,0x483122d5,0x35d8,0x1340)..BO



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme1n1 : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p7   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p8   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p7   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p8   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p7   : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p8   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: CDE63859-0DC5-4C68-999B-FFC6DB911ACB
               Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3     567296 1793862286 1793294991 855.1G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 1998667776 2000404686    1736911 848.1M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 1793863680 1793882111      18432     9M BIOS boot
nvme0n1p6 1793882112 1823178751   29296640    14G Linux swap
nvme0n1p7 1823178752 1881772031   58593280    28G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p8 1881772032 1998667775  116895744  55.8G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk nvme1n1: 27.3 GiB, 29260513280 bytes, 57149440 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x73736572
          Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
nvme1n1p1      1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
nvme1n1p2      1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931.6G 6c unknown
nvme1n1p3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
nvme1n1p4        27722122   27722568        447 223.5K  0 Empty
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 114.6 GiB, 123010547712 bytes, 240254976 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x483122d5
      Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *        0 4284223 4284224    2G  0 Empty
sda2       13784   18711    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:123GB:scsi:512:512:unknown: USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1:;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:INTEL HBRPEKNX0203A:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:918GB:918GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:918GB:918GB:9437kB:::bios_grub;
6:918GB:933GB:15.0GB:linux-swap(v1)::;
7:933GB:963GB:30.0GB:ext4::;
8:963GB:1023GB:59.9GB:ext4::;
4:1023GB:1024GB:889MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
nvme1n1:29.3GB:nvme:512:512:loop:INTEL HBRPEKNX0203AO:;
1:0.00B:29.3GB:29.3GB:ntfs::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE          UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda         iso9660         2020-08-06-22-59-01-00                                                    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS amd64 
├─sda1      iso9660         2020-08-06-22-59-01-00               483122d5-01                          Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS amd64 
└─sda2      vfat            EC34-71CF                            483122d5-02                          Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS amd64 
nvme0n1     isw_raid_member                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat            D862-97CF                            ccf28906-447b-4ad4-ad94-d535fc48b4ce SYSTEM                   EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2 isw_raid_member                                      19c22a04-a819-4080-9ef6-2b66d5c301b9                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs            F65A64805A64400B                     0e68f550-6835-4f80-be89-319fe3d58f84 OS                       Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs            9E22859A22857853                     afc7bf3e-a297-4893-b3e7-c2c802a81ff1 RECOVERY                 Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p5 isw_raid_member                                      398f6dd4-f104-4041-9449-7a11ec4136cd                          
├─nvme0n1p6 swap            ceb25a95-3e46-4426-b985-5ff06eb4fb31 ef865bf2-701c-4498-93c8-f15dfc691a49                          
├─nvme0n1p7 ext4            a94599b5-b934-4ade-9cc4-454ef60888c8 2de7d8f6-4405-4445-aaa9-8fc42871acff                          
└─nvme0n1p8 ext4            154d46c6-ec2e-4e85-9151-b65a7e9d1bef ce881266-e26f-4d3e-b0de-0a9594516b31                          
nvme1n1     isw_raid_member                                                                                                    

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

       Avail Use% Mounted on
sda        0 100% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda    ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048

====================== sda/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =======================

Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disc for defects

==================== sda: Location of files loaded by Grub =====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on md/imsm0


Unknown BootLoader on md/imsm1


Unknown BootLoader on sda

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f3 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 02  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  31 c9 5a 51 b4 08 cd 13  5b 0f b6 c6 40 50 83 e1  |1.ZQ....[...@P..|
00000080  3f 51 f7 e1 53 52 50 bb  00 7c b9 04 00 66 a1 b0  |?Q..SRP..|...f..|
00000090  07 e8 44 00 0f 82 80 00  66 40 80 c7 02 e2 f2 66  |..D.....f@.....f|
000000a0  81 3e 40 7c fb c0 78 70  75 09 fa bc ec 7b ea 44  |.>@|..xpu....{.D|
000000b0  7c 00 00 e8 83 00 69 73  6f 6c 69 6e 75 78 2e 62  ||.....isolinux.b|
000000c0  69 6e 20 6d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 72 20 63 6f  |in missing or co|
000000d0  72 72 75 70 74 2e 0d 0a  66 60 66 31 d2 66 03 06  |rrupt...f`f1.f..|
000000e0  f8 7b 66 13 16 fc 7b 66  52 66 50 06 53 6a 01 6a  |.{f...{fRfP.Sj.j|
000000f0  10 89 e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b  c0 e4 06 88 e1 88 c5 92  |...f.6.{........|
00000100  f6 36 ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1  41 b8 01 02 8a 16 f2 7b  |.6.{....A......{|
00000110  cd 13 8d 64 10 66 61 c3  e8 1e 00 4f 70 65 72 61  |...d.fa....Opera|
00000120  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 20 6c 6f 61 64  |ting system load|
00000130  20 65 72 72 6f 72 2e 0d  0a 5e ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62  | error...^....>b|
00000140  04 b3 07 cd 10 3c 0a 75  f1 cd 18 f4 eb fd 00 00  |.....<.u........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  94 80 00 00 00 00 00 00  d5 22 31 48 00 00 80 00  |........."1H....|
000001c0  01 00 00 82 e0 fd 00 00  00 00 40 5f 41 00 00 fe  |..........@_A...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff d8 35  00 00 40 13 00 00 00 00  |.......5..@.....|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[105931]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 20954: /bin/bash
mdadm: (IMSM): Unsupported attributes : 3000000
mdadm: Unsupported attributes in IMSM metadata.Arrays activation is blocked.
mdadm: Cannot activate member /md127/0 in /dev/md/imsm0.
mdadm: (IMSM): Unsupported attributes : 3000000
mdadm: Unsupported attributes in IMSM metadata.Arrays activation is blocked.
mdadm: Cannot activate member /md126/0 in /dev/md/imsm1.
mdadm: (IMSM): Unsupported attributes : 3000000
mdadm: Unsupported attributes in IMSM metadata.Arrays activation is blocked.
mdadm: Cannot activate member /md126/1 in /dev/md/imsm1.


=================== blkid (filtered) before raid activation: ===================
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="D862-97CF" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="ccf28906-447b-4ad4-ad94-d535fc48b4ce"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="OS" UUID="F65A64805A64400B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="0e68f550-6835-4f80-be89-319fe3d58f84"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="9E22859A22857853" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="afc7bf3e-a297-4893-b3e7-c2c802a81ff1"
/dev/nvme0n1p7: UUID="a94599b5-b934-4ade-9cc4-454ef60888c8" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2de7d8f6-4405-4445-aaa9-8fc42871acff"
/dev/nvme0n1p8: UUID="154d46c6-ec2e-4e85-9151-b65a7e9d1bef" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ce881266-e26f-4d3e-b0de-0a9594516b31"
/dev/nvme1n1: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/nvme0n1: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="ceb25a95-3e46-4426-b985-5ff06eb4fb31" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="ef865bf2-701c-4498-93c8-f15dfc691a49"
/dev/sda1: UUID="2020-08-06-22-59-01-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="483122d5" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="483122d5-01"
/dev/sda2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="EC34-71CF" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="483122d5-02"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="19c22a04-a819-4080-9ef6-2b66d5c301b9"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: PARTUUID="398f6dd4-f104-4041-9449-7a11ec4136cd"
dmraid -si -c
no block devices found
dmraid -ay:
no block devices found
dmraid -sa -c:
no block devices found
mdadm --assemble --scan

mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/imsm0 metadata=imsm UUID=6aa77994:e239329e:b440a3f4:86e24ce7
ARRAY /dev/md/imsm1 metadata=imsm UUID=f40688fa:3bdd6bfc:db829b87:28c5d34f
Error code 32
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p1 : Error code 32
Error code 12
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p3 : Error code 12
Error code 21
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p4 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p4 : Error code 21
Error code 32
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p7 : Error code 32
Error code 32
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p8 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p8 : Error code 32
Error code 32
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p1 : Error code 32
Error code 12
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p3 : Error code 12
Error code 21
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p4 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p4 : Error code 21
Error code 32
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p7 : Error code 32
Error code 32
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p8 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p8 : Error code 32
Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

([Ubuntu pastebin link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sbmrgmpVfs/))

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling `Secure Boot` in the BIOS

Comment: I checked, its already disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: Still, the problem continues. No grub menu, unable to manually boot Ubuntu from Bios.